# Intellij Mdoule Dependency Found no modules to depend on

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module

I recently upgraded to IntelliJ CE 2016.3. I have 2 modules: module A and module B. Module A is a dependency of Module B. When I try to add a module dependency to B (by going to "Open Module Settings" -> Module B -> + Module Dependency), I get a pop up saying

Module Dependency...

Found no module to depend on

However, if I click on any other modules in my project, I just see a list of modules to add.

IntelliJ Version: CE 2016.3

System: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: Start using maven

Comment: Not an option at my work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, the reason I see this error message is because Module B already has all other modules marked as dependencies.